# Upload image to mongoDB and get back the url of the image: Multer

Tags: mongodb, express, multer, image-upload

I'm trying to upload an image to MongoDB, but when I visualize it in mongoCompass it only shows its "_id". So I don't know if it went through or not.

**I need to:**

- Store the image in the DB
- Get the image's URL after it's stored there.

I'm using Express, Multer, Body-parser, fs, mongoose

**Here's my app.js**

```
const express = require("express"),
      app = express(),
      bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
      fs = require("fs"),
      multer = require("multer"),
      mongoose = require("mongoose");

      mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/Images");  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded(
      { extended:true }
))

app.set("view engine","ejs");

//Schema
var imgSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    img:{data:Buffer,contentType: String,nom:String}
});
var image = mongoose.model("image",imgSchema); 


// SET STORAGE
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'uploaded-' + Date.now()+".png")
    }
  })

  var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
  

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("index");
})

app.get("/show",(req,res)=>{
    image.find().toArray(function (err,result){
       const imgArray = result.map(element =>element._id);
       console.log(imgArray);
       if(err){
           return console.error(err);
       }
       res.send(imgArray)
   })
});

app.post("/uploadphoto",upload.single('myImage'),(req,res)=>{
    var img = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
    var encode_img = img.toString('base64');
    var final_img = {
        contentType:req.file.mimetype,
        image:new Buffer(encode_img,'base64'),
        nom:"hi"
    };
    image.create(final_img,function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(result.img.Buffer);
            console.log("Saved To database");
            res.contentType(final_img.contentType);
            res.send(final_img.image);
        }
    })
})
//Code to start server
app.listen(2000,function () {
      console.log("Server Started at PORT 2000");
})
```

[this is what mongo shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCNHR.png)

[This is the image upload folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL6MG.png)

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: this is what my console shows: 
undefined
Saved To database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is here
This Github repo has the answer detailed.
https://github.com/AnasGara/Upload-Image-Express-Mutler